# How to select a table by parameters in jasper report using java in eclipse?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a button. When I hit it. It creates a table in database with name+billno+date. and inserts all details like product name and etc into the database.

Now I want to when the new table is created, after that jasper report fetch that newly created table and show it in table of jasper report.

For that I created a parameter.

```
Hashmap param = new Hashmap();
param.put("TABLE" , name+bill+date);
```

After that I created a table in jasper report and tried to do this query.

```
select * from $P{TABLE}
```

But it throws an error.

Comment: Can you please attach that error message to the answer?

Comment: it say no table found.. thats true because that table does not exist. because table will create each time when i hit the button..

Answer (score 1):

You have to correct the query using `$P!{}` syntax (note the `!` char between `P` and `{`):

```
SELECT * FROM $P!{TABLE}
```

Where `$P!{TABLE}` is replaced with the text value of the parameter (table name in this case).

`$P{}` syntax can be used in the case the parameter is used as standard SQL parameter, it means that the query can be executed using a prepared statement. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM bill WHERE id = $P{ID}
```

Where prepared statement is then:

```
SELECT * FROM bill WHERE id = ?
```

---

**Side note:** It looks like a little bit crazy scenario to create separate table for each combination of *name + billno + date*. Imagine that on some day you will need to implement search through all those records - how you will create SELECT query over all those tables?

It would be better to have one table (`bill` for example) with `id` column as a primary key, and other columns like `name`, `billnum` and `date` and pass that id into the Jasper report as a parameter. Products can be stored in the related table `bill_item` and relate them to `bill` by `bill_id` column. Then in Jasper report you can `SELECT * FROM bill b LEFT JOIN bill_item i ON i.bill_id = b.id WHERE b.id = $P{ID}`. But I'm just guessing how can look your data model.

Comment: i am creating a billing software. so to save and show past bills ,  i create a seperate table for each bill. if you have better idea to save bills you can suggest. thanks

Comment: and i also gave a delete option to delete bills(table) and as the table name contains customer name , bill no , and date , user can find the bill by a little effort of scrolling.  as bill no. is in serial .  i don't think user have to do more effort...            what you say...  is this a  good idea or bad ?

Comment: and when i didn't saw your answer ,, i created a temporary table by default that will insert the table that contains item_name etc.  and it willl get deleted and created after every transaction..  and it worked.      And i changed the whole code . so , now i am not able to check your suggestion.. sorry and thanks for your time